# Repeating values for in a random bytes generator in c++

Tags: c++11, random, byte, aes, cbc-mode

I have made a random bytes generator for intialization vector of CBC mode AES implementation,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>

using bytes_randomizer =    std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, uint8_t>;

int main()
{
bytes_randomizer br;
char x[3];
uint8_t data[100];
std::generate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ref(br));

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    sprintf(x, "%x", data[i]);
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
}
```

But the problem is it gives the same sequence over and over, I found a solution to on Stack which is to use `srand()` but this seems to work only for `rand()`.

Any solutions to this, also is there a better way to generate nonce for generating an unpredictable Initialization Vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error C2338: invalid template argument for independent_bits_engine: N4659 29.6.1.1 [rand.req.genl]/1f requires one of unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long
>
> Error C2338   note: char, signed char, unsigned char, int8_t, and uint8_t are not allowed

You can't use `uint8_t` in `independent_bits_engine`, at least on Visual Studio 2017. I don't know where and how you managed to compile it.

As the answer [DeiDei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529962/7735711) suggests, seeding the engine is an important part to get random values. It's also same with `rand()`.

`srand(time(nullptr));` is required to get random values by using `rand()`.

You can use:

```
using bytes_randomizer = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, unsigned long>;

std::random_device rd;
bytes_randomizer br(rd());
```

Some example output:

```
25
94
bd
6d
6c
a4
```

Comment: Well I am using codblocks 16.01which allows using uint8_t

Comment: Can you suggest something on the second question?

Comment: Best solution I've read earlier was mersenne twister @Nilesh, check it out.

Comment: As per my knowledge c++11 uses mersenne twister already and I'm compiling all my programs on  c++11 codeblocks compiler

Comment: I'm talking about this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/ I never knew it was default, but I know that it's one of the best soultions available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seed the engine, otherwise a default seed will be used which will give you the same sequence every time. This is the same as the usage of `srand` and `rand`.

Try:

```
std::random_device rd;
bytes_randomizer br(rd());
```